# How do I scroll through the autocomplete options in emacs-jedi (besides arrow keys)

Tags: emacs, emacs-jedi

Up and down arrow keys work but I was wondering if there was another option on the home row. If not, how do I set it to something else? (emacs noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/blob/master/jedi.el#L36) uses [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/auto-complete.el#L442) under the hood

These are also supported (besides the default arrows):

<kbd>M-n</kbd> Next item

<kbd>M-p</kbd> Previous item

If you wanted to change them you could do something like this:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-c j") 'ac-next)
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-c k") 'ac-previous)
```